# What is this Strange Quote Showing up in my Wordpress Shortcode that is Breaking the Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-shortcode

When I place my shortcode into a Wordpress page it looks fine, but when I load the page up the quote turns into a strange quote.

Any ideas on why that strange quote might be replacing the normal quote?

[image]

Comment: Are you editing in html-mode or visual-mode? I'd suggest taking the whole shortcode out, edit it in a text-editor (replacing the quotes with new characters typed from the text-editor) then put it back into the page via the html-editor.

Comment: I agree with @admcfajn, editting in visual mode cutting and pasting text from the internet causes issues.